# Шифра Цезаря на C++

Tags: visual-c++

Написал я на днях **дешифратор шифра Цезаря** на C++. Но возникла проблема с идентификатором `encryption`. Компилятор пишет, что он не определен. Указывал прототипы функций `void Crypt();` и `void encrypt();` до использования. Не помогло. Исходный код программы я оставил ниже.

Программа написана на Visual Studio 2017. Код ошибки **E0020** (если потребуется).

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string s;
    getline(cin, s);

    vector<int> vec(26);


    for (auto& c : s)
    {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            vec[c - 'a']++;
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            vec[c - 'A']++;
    }

    int max_index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (vec[i] > vec[max_index])
            max_index = i;
    }
        int key = max_index - 4;
        while (key < 0)
            key += 26;

        cout << encryption(s, 26 - key) << endl;

}
```

Что не так я не знаю. Компилировать с этой ошибкой пытался, но результаты не очень. Расшифровать Цезаря не получилось. Кто встречался с такой проблемой и знает решения прошу написать.

Comment: А откуда вы взяли функцию `encryption()`? Ибо я тоже не вижу её объявления в Вашем коде.

Comment: функция encryption() указана в конце кода. cout << encryption(s, 26 - key) << endl; При добавлении функции которая отвечает за данную часть кода происходит ошибка.

Comment: Функция должна быть объявлена ДО её вызова. Если Вы пробовали `void encrypt();` добавить перед функцией `main`, то Вы пропустили параметры (судя по вашему вызову, `string` и `int`).

Comment: @МихаилМуругов эту функцию я указывал и неоднократно, ошибка остается на том же месте)

Comment: Быть такого не может. Покажите Ваш исправленный вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, настояльно рекомендую вам, прочитать базовые понятия языка, ещё раз.

Во вторых, как уже вам говорили, Вы НЕ объявили функцию `encryption()` и так же не инициализировали её прототип в `int main()`, на что вполне резонно ругается компилятор.

Для того, чтобы использовать эту функцию, объявите её перед `int main ()`, задайте ей аргументы, в вашем случае это `string &s, int *i` дайте этой функции логику, что она должна делать и объявите прототип этой функции, непосредственно в функции `int main()`, тогда компилятор перестанет ругаться на не объявленую функцию.

Именно это вам пытались донести...